# Do the SNCF fidelity "points monnaie" expire when switching status?

Tags: trains, france, loyalty-programs, sncf

I am currently a member of the [SNCF fidelity program](https://www.programme-voyageur.sncf.com) and I am a "Grand Voyageur", a status that lets you collect points ("points monnaie") for every euro spent. Soon, it will be the anniversary of my membership so my status may change. In my case, as I did not collect enough "points statut", I will switch to the "Voyageur" status. This status does not have "points monnaie". Will I lose all of these "points monnaie" (if so I should try to redeem them) or are they independent from my status? I did not dig much in the help yet, the basic interface of my account does not mention any expiration date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My membership's anniversary recently happened and I am back to the `Voyageur` status. I could in fact keep my `points monnaie` and use them for rewards. I could see some lines in the conditions about the expiration of these points though:

> Le solde de points monnaie d’un client qui passe du statut Grand Voyageur au statut Voyageur est supprimé 6 mois après son entrée dans le statut Voyageur.

Which means that 6 months after switching from `Grand Voyageur` to `Voyageur` status, my `points monnaie` will expire. And indeed, every time I connected on the fidelity website, I got a notification that my points will expire, with the specific expiry date.

It is also written that I cannot earn these `points monnaie` (not `points statut`) when in the `Voyageur` status:

> Un client au statut Voyageur ne cumule pas de points mais des trajets lui permettant de recevoir des Codes avantage.